# Unable to PGP Encrypt/Decrypt Excel file using OpenPGP.js

Tags: openpgp, openpgp.js

Tried encrypting and decrypting excel files the same way I am doing for csv/txt files but I am not able to.

**Encryption**

```
var rawMessage= fs.readFileSync(path)
await openpgp.initWorker({ path: 'openpgp.worker.js' }); // set the relative web worker path
const publicKeyArmored = readFile(publicKeyPath);
const { data: encrypted } = await openpgp.encrypt({
    message: openpgp.message.fromBinary(new Uint8Array(rawMessage)),  // input as Message object
    publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(publicKeyArmored)).keys, // for encryption
    armor: true,
    compression: openpgp.enums.compression.zip
});
```

**Decryption**

```
var rawMessage= fs.readFileSync(path)
const privateKeyArmored = readFile(privateKeyPath);
const { keys: [privateKey] } = await openpgp.key.readArmored(privateKeyArmored);
await privateKey.decrypt(passphrase);
const { data: decrypted } = await openpgp.decrypt({
  message: await openpgp.message.readArmored(encryptedData), //               // parse armored message
      privateKeys: [privateKey]                                           // for decryption
  });
```

Looking for quick resolution

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is excel and the data is compressed, the text output will not help. Openpgp by default returns output as text. Solution is to get the decrypted output as binary and then save it in the file.

```
const { data: decrypted } = await openpgp.decrypt({
  message: await openpgp.message.readArmored(encryptedData), // parse armored message
  privateKeys: [privateKey],   // for decryption
  format: 'binary'
});
```